# Pyspark dataframe conversion to pandas df is taking too long (12 hours for a 100x700 table) on google dataproc

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new to Spark and GCP dataproc in general. My plan is to perform aggregate functions to condense a data frame with 70000 rows and 200 columns into a data frame with 700 rows and 100 columns to be used in a pandas-scikit-learn pipeline.

1. What I did:

- Open a dataproc single node cluster with 16 CPUs and 30 Gb. I think this should be more than enough to do my proof-of-concept work
- I read table 1 from a project dataset stored on google cloud storage

```
df_qm = spark.read \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .option("table", table1) \
  .load()

df_qm.printSchema()
```

- I confirm that the table schema is printed out.
- I then performed a bunch of aggregation, some using native spark functions like select,groupby, order, some using my UDFs.
- I created a couple more dfs along the way: `df2 = F(df1)`, etc.
- All these above steps took about 20 min
- Now in the last step, my `dffinal` is created using a UDF I created. This took 2 hours.
- Now when I did `dfpd = dffinal.toPandas()`, this took 12 hours and counting. To remind you, dffinal is a Spark df with only 100 columns and 700 rows. From my experience, this is not normal, and there must be something wrong in my Spark df transformation.

2. Could you please give me suggestions on where I should check to solve this? Since I am new to DataProc, please provide as much detail as possible. Any advice on spark dataframe best practice would be welcome as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Is spark come configured to use "local" or "yarn"? How much memory is allocated for the driver/executor?

Comment: I am not sure, David. How do I check for this?

Comment: Actually I have now figured out a way to temporarily solve this problem. I just need to go back to where `df.show()` stopped working, do `df.cache()` and `pdf = df.toPandas()` will work just fine. Would love to know more about the practice of memory management in Spark though.

Comment: I added .cache() but still take so many time